# What is the minimum number of stars of destiny you must recruit in Suikoden I?

Tags: suikoden

What is the minimum number of stars you need to recruit to complete the game?

Answer (score 4):

47, including the character you start with.

The 46 characters who automatically join your party during the storyline are: Gremio, Cleo, Viktor, Mathiu, Camille, Tai Ho, Yam Koo, Luc, Lepant, Eileen, Giovanni, Krin, Juppo, Varkas, Sydonia, Kirkis, Viki, Valeria, Kuromimi, Humphrey, Sylvina, Stallion, Flik, Gen, Kamandol, Kimberly, Tesla, Liukan, Kasumi, Kessler, Ledon, Kun To, Mose, Ronnie Bell, Alen, Grenseal, Fukien, Hix, Tengaar, Milia, Joshua, Futch, Griffith, Warren, Kasim and Taggart.

You need all 108 stars to get the good ending.